# how to call a javascript function from a geogebra script?

Tags: javascript, computational-geometry, geogebra

In Geogebra let's define a JavaScript global function from a button (property):

```
function ggbOnInit() {
}

function test(par) {
  return par * math.random();
}
```

How do I call that function from a Geogebra script attached to that button ("on click" property)?

The following Geogebra script:

```
Sequence[test(3),k,1,5]
```

launches an error message " unknown command test", whereas a sequence of five random numbers between 0 and 3 were waited.

Answer (score 3):

I found this possible solution.

Create a button and in the "*On Click*" section, with "*JavaScript*" selected at the bottom, insert the code:

```
ggbApplet.evalCommand("list={0}");
if (! ggbApplet.exists("par")) {ggbApplet.evalCommand("par=200")}; 
for(var i =1;i<5;i++) 
ggbApplet.evalCommand("SetValue[list," +i+",  par* random()]");
```

The *par* parameter can be set as a Geogebra variable or inside the code (that last value will be used in case the variable doesn't exist).

Anyway I couldn't find how to use a *function* in the *Global Javascript* tab or how to use the Javascript math.random() command.

The problem is that the JavaScript commands available inside Geogebra are probably a limited set of the JavaScript available outside it, but I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 2):

In order to call your Global JavaScript function your "On click" script must be of type JavaScript and not GeoGebra Script.

Comment: Try to provide more explanation to your answers, like a possible code example. See [How to answer page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for help in improving your answer.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure whether you want to get five random integers or decimal numbers. If you want to get five random integers between 0 and 3 you can easily do it with GeoGebra scripting.
You can first create an empty list writing for example list={} into Input Bar and then fill it with a button or create it dynamically with a button.

Create a button, open Object Properties, go to Scripting tab and inside On Click tab write next line:
list=Sequence[RandomBetween[0,3],k,1,5]

Be sure that you've chosen "GeoGebra Script" in drop-down menu.

IF YOU WANT FIVE RANDOM DECIMAL NUMBERS between 0 and 3 do the same but with little different code line:
list1=Sequence[random()+RandomBetween[0,2],k,1,5]

Hope this helped...

Comment: you've provided a workaround but have not answered the question: how to call a JS function from a GG script.